# Perl Catalyst search function to search multiple columns

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have a table in SQLite database and I have a schema called Account. I also have a form that searches for users. In my controller I do this:

```
my $params ||= $c->req->parameters; # Don't know what the difference is between ||= and =, did that way because someone had done it to and it works
my $search_term = $params->{search};

if( $c->request->params{submit} )
{
    $c->stash->{search_term} = $search_term;

    $c->stash->{search_results} = $c->model("DB::Account")->find({
        firstname => { like => "%$search_term%" },
    }) if $c->stash->{search_term};
}
```

Then in my view I have something like this.

```
[% IF search_results > 0 %]
  [% FOREACH results IN search_results %]
    [% results.email %] <br/>
    [% results.firstname %]
[% END %]
```

The above code works fine. What I want to do is search the table matching with `firstname`, `lastname` or other columns, instead of just one column.

I am fairly new to Catalyst framework and Perl (had done stuff with perl, but not very advanced), so any help and tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You should escape your variable to prevent XSS: [% results.email | html %] <br/>[% results.firstname | html %]
Also, in this example, your [% IF ... %] statement is not needed and is probably wrong (IF search_results.size > 0)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, will try those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for this:

```
my $params ||= $c->req->parameters;
```

the same as:

```
my $params = $params || $c->req->parameters; # when $params is not defined 
                                             # it will be used the part after ||
```

As for searching row from a table. The method `find` will be find just a ONE row.

```
$c->stash->{search_results} = $c->model("DB::Account")->find({
        firstname => { like => "%$search_term%" },            
});
```

In order to find ALL rows you should use methods `search` or `search_rs`. Something like this:

```
$c->stash->{search_results} = $c->model("DB::Account")->search({
        firstname => { like => "%$search_term%" },
        lastname => "Smith",
        email => "jsmith@abc.de"
})
```

That's all! For more info you have to read [DBIx::Class::ResultSet](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aResultSet)

**UPD**

In order to view result in your tt file you should use this:

```
[% WHILE (row = search_results.next) %]
[% row.email %]
[% row.firstname %]
[% END %]
```

Comment: why `lastname => "Smith"`, `email => "jsmith@abc.de"`? Can I do lastname => {like => "%$search_term%"}, email => {like => "%$search_term"}, ?

Comment: but then it returns nothing, how would I generate the list in my view?

Comment: Try use `search_rs` instead of `search`.

Comment: no results, I will play with it and let you know what happens

Comment: @Grigor show me your Account.pm file from DB model and write which sql statement would you like to do?

Comment: I recteated the database and it worked, now it won't show the results in the view when I do results.email Is there another way of accessing the results?

Comment: Edem, you are the best. Worked with no problems. I appreciate everyone's help.